# Connect QlikView to Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, qlikview

I am new to Neo4J and qlikview. I need to connect these two to create reports. Can anyone give me step by step process. I am asked to connect using JDBC, but some body please tell me how to do that too

Answer (score 3):

A simple search would have led you to http://tiqview.tumblr.com/post/24953750981/working-with-graph-data-from-neo4j-in-qlikview

There's more information about Neo4j at http://neo4j.org, the JDBC driver at http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc